# 造反有理　革命無罪: What are the standard English translations of this?

Tags: translation

Perhaps one is "To rebel is justified / Revolution is no crime."

This however does not seem to me to fully capture the phrase.

I was wondering if there are perhaps other standard translations?

Answer (score 3):

*right to rebel! right to revolution!*

or

*Rebellion justified, Revolution legitimated!*

Answer (score 1):

> Innocent it is to make revolution, and justified it is to rebel!

The quotation is reversed, its order should be 革命無罪 造反有理. I did not find it in the *quotations of Chairman Mao*, though some references show he said the second part of this slogan, which was later composed into a famous propaganda song.

Comment: @deutschZuid 革命 is the positive way of expressing the same thing as "revolt"...pls refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublespeak

Comment: Um.. renovate just doesn't make sense here. You 'renovate' a house by repainting/refurnishing it. It has nothing to do with 革命, which is usually translated as 'revolutionise'.

Answer (score 0):

well, you need to know the background of this .....you can't  just simply translate from what it looks like....there were about 10 years of history in this one sentence.,.... get to know the history first, then you will understand it.

Comment: In that period of history, it basically means that : you can do what ever you want, as long as "in name of Revolution" to do it. it would be the right thing to do.  That history is not easy to understand for ppl from west..